# Powershell Nested Replace

Tags: powershell

I am looping through multiple remote machines looking for a certain string to appear in a log file (other things are being collected from each device but for simplicity I've left that out). When I find them I want to return them and write to a central log, this is all working perfectly, except I want to tidy up the central log, by removing information from each string.

So I start with

```
  **28-Jan-2021 01:31:49,TCPServer.run(),3,JMX TCP Server running on 8085
```

But want to save to Central Log

```
   28-Jan-2021 01:31:349,JMX TCP 8085
```

And I can achieve this using the below, but surely there is a more succinct way to do this? (have played about with -Replace but no joy)

```
 $JMXString8085 = $JMXString8085.Replace("TCPServer.run(),3,","")
 $JMXString8085 = $JMXString8085.Replace("}","")
 $JMXString8085 = $JMXString8085.Replace(" Server running on","")
```

Comment: Why are you attempting to replace `@{Line=` before the start of the string sample you've shown? Did you already output something (output from `Select-String` perhaps?) to file and are reading it back now?

Comment: Yes you are correct will remove it - still the question still remains the same, how do a nested replace.

Comment: FWIW you can probably solve your problem by replacing a statement like `... |Select Line` with `... |Select -ExpandProperty Line` somewhere in your script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [...] surely there is a more succinct way to do this? (have played about with `-Replace` but no joy)

There is, and `-replace` can indeed help us here. `-replace` is a *regex operator*, it performs text replacement using [*regular expressions*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions) - patterns we can use to *describe* strings that we might not be quite sure the exact contents of.

For a string like:

```
$string = '**28-Jan-2021 01:31:49,TCPServer.run(),3,JMX TCP Server running on 8085'
```

... we could describe the fields in between the commas, and use that to tell PowerShell to only preserve some of them for example:

```
PS ~> $string -replace '^\*\*([^,]+),[^,]+,[^,]+,([^,]+) Server running on (\d+)', '$1,$2 $3'
28-Jan-2021 01:31:49,JMX TCP 8085
```

The pattern I used in this example (`^\*\*([^,]+),[^,]+,[^,]+,([^,]+) Server running on (\d+)`) might seem a bit alien at first, so let's try and break it down:

```
^                 # carret means "start of string"
 \*\*             # Then we look for two literal asterisks
 (                # This open parens means "start of a capture group"
  [^,]+           # This means "1 or more characters that are NOT a comma", captures the timestamp
 )                # And this matching closing parens means "end of capture group"
 ,                # Match a literal comma
 [^,]+            # Same as above, this one will match "TCPServer.run()"
 ,                # Same as above
 [^,]+            # You probably get the point by now
 ,                # ...
 (                # This open parens means "start ANOTHER capture group"
  [^,]+?          # The `?` at the end means "capture as few as possible", captures "JMX TCP"
 )                # And this matching closing parens still means "end of capture group"
  Server...       # Just match the literal string " Server running on "
 (                # Finally a THIRD capture group
  \d+             # capturing "1 or more digits", in your case "8085"
 )                # and end of group
```

Since our pattern "captures" a number of substrings, we can now refer to these individual substrings in out substition pattern `$1,$2 $3`, and PowerShell will replace the `$N` references with the capture group value.

Answer (score 1):

here is yet another way to do the job. [*grin*]

what it does ...

- assigns the string to a $Var
- chains `.Replace()` to get rid of the asterisks and the "Server" phrase
- splits on the `,` chars
- takes the 1st & 4th items from that split
- joins them into one string with `,`  [comma then space] for a delimiter
- assigns that to a new $Var
- displays the results

the code ...

```
$InString = '**28-Jan-2021 01:31:49,TCPServer.run(),3,JMX TCP Server running on 8085'
$OutString = ($InString.Replace('**', '').Replace('Server running on ', '').Split(',')[0, 3]) -join ', '

$OutString
```

output ...

```
28-Jan-2021 01:31:49, JMX TCP 8085
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a powershell guy, but I am using the one-liner below in my azure pipeline:

```
(Get-Content -path 'myFilePath' -Raw) -replace "text-to-replace-1","replacing-text-1" -replace "text-to-replace-2","replacing-text-2" | Set-Content 'myFilePath'
```

Nest as many `-replace` as you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can "or" the patterns together in regex, backslashing the regex characters you want taken literally (at least the parentheses).  You don't address the 2 stars at the beginning.  The 2nd arg to -replace is null by default.  There's no "}" in the input string.

```
$string = '**28-Jan-2021 01:31:49,TCPServer.run(),3,JMX TCP Server running on 8085'


[regex]::escape('TCPServer.run(),3,* Server running on')

TCPServer\.run\(\),3,\*\ Server\ running\ on


$string -replace 'TCPServer.run\(\),3,|\*| Server running on'

28-Jan-2021 01:31:49,JMX TCP 8085
```